# Add 10 or more listings in Google Maps programmatically

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I am developing a MVC App for a client and he has come to me with a really strange request. I think the answer to this question should be a straight **NO** but I want to make sure.

The client wants the Google Bulk Upload Listing process Automated. My thoughts are **this is impossible atleast through any Google API**. You may be able to simulate a user Uploading the data to Google by following instructions in this [`link`](https://support.google.com/places/answer/178024?hl=en&topic=1656882&ctx=topic#6), but I dont think Google will take to kindly to that.

```
Step 1: Visit Google Places
Step 2: Sign in or create a Google account
Step 3: Enter business information in a spreadsheet
Step 4: Upload your spreadsheet
Step 5: Check your listings for errors
Step 6: Request bulk upload verification
Step 7: Manage and upload additional listings
```

Before I give an answer can you **please confirm that this is Impossible with any of Google API.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer would be no.

If you build in some workaround and google finds out - your client(s) account(s) may be blocked and the app will malfunction.

I think a custom video tutorial would be better.